# XNA how to store and draw a 2d map?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a problem and I am not sure how to approach the solution.
I need to create a 2D map editor for my XNA app., with a certain number of tiles.
Say a map will be 50x100 tiles.

I am not sure what data structure to use for the map, tiles and how to store it on the hard-drive for later loading.

What I am thinking now is this. I will store the map in a text file like so:

```
//x, y, ground_type, object_type
0, 0, 1, 0
0, 1, 2, 1
```

where 0=Grass, 1=River etcc for ground terrain, and 0=Nothing, 1=Wall for object types.

Then I will have a Game Component Map class that can read that file or create a new one from scratch:

```
class Map : DrawableGameComponent {
      //These are things like grass, whater, sand...
      Tile ground_tiles[,];
      //These are things like walls that can be destroyed
      Tile object_tiles[,];

      public Map(Game game, String filepath){
          for line in open(filepath){
               //Set the x,y tile to a new tile
               ground_tiles[line[0], line[1]] = new Tile(line[3])
               object_tiles[line[0], line[1]] = new Tile(line[4])
          }
      }

      public Map(Game game, int width, int heigth){
        //constructor
        init_map()
      }
      private void init_map(){
          //initialize all the ground_tiles
          //to "grass"
          for i,j width, heigth{
              ground_tiles[i,j] = new Tile(TILE.GRASS)
          }


      public override Draw(game_time){
            for tile in tiles: 
                sprite_batch.draw(tile.texture, tile.x, tile.y etc..)

      }
```

My Tile class will probably NOT be a game component.
I am still not quite sure how to handle collision detection for example between a bullet originating from the player with the map object. Should that be handled by the Map class or some kind of super Manager class?

Any hints are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but I decided on (ground_type, object_type) pairs.
So an input file like

```
0, 1
0, 0,
0, 0,
1, 1
```

with mappings like: 
GROUND = {0:grass, 1:road}
OBJECTS = {0:none, 1:crate}
and the width=2 and height=2 of map will product the following:

```
grass+crate  |   grass 
grass        |   road+crate
```

Granted, I have to know the width/height of the map in order to make sense of the file. I might put that in the input file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store it as:

```
Height 
Width
GroundType * (Height * Width)
```

Giving something like

```
4 
4
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

It's both easier and more compact. :)  As for in-game storage, a 2D array is perfect for this, unless you have other specific needs.  A typical collision detection technique is to  have a broad phase done by a the physics subsystem, with bounding spheres or axis-aligned bounding boxes for example, and then have the pairs of possibly colliding objects to compute if there was in fact a collision.

Your tile class should probably not be a component, unless you have a very compelling reason.

Edit: Forgot the object type up there, but it'd be easy to integrate it too.